# Why can't I access to some elements of document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in programming and I would like to understand why I can access to some elements in a certain way and why I can't to some other in the same way.

There is the code:

```
    const cImg = document.querySelectorAll('#cImg');
    console.log('c :', cImg);

    console.log('element : ', cImg['0'].offsetHeight);

    cImg.forEach(element => {
      console.log('e :', element.clientWidth);
    });
```

I see in the console.log of the "cImg", the elements `offsetHeight`and `clientWidth`

[image]

[image]

If I'm trying to log ofsetHeilght in the `forEach` I get this error

[image]

[image]

but if I'm doing it like this : `cImg['0'].offsetHeight` I have the correct display "399"
and if i want to see the element "clientWidht" in the `forEach` it works, I get the display "298"

I don't understand why, because both elements are in the "cImg array".

Someone have an explication ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[edit]

To get to the CSS in an element, through javascript, you need to go through `element.style`.

Try

`element.style.offsetHeight`

[edit 2] No, it's not because to get CSS it's element.style.height and javascript can't get CSS code. Too much wine a Saturday night. :P

---

[edit 2]

```js
function displayWidth() {
  const cImg = document.querySelectorAll('.cImg');

  console.log('c :', cImg);
  
  if (cImg.length) {
    console.log('element : ', cImg[0].offsetHeight);

    cImg.forEach(element => {
      console.log('e :', element.clientWidth);
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<body onload="displayWidth()">

<div class="cImg">
askldajsldkjasdklasd
</div>

<div class="cImg">
askldajsldkjasdklasd
</div>


<div class="cImg">
askldajsldkjasdklasd
</div>


<div class="cImg">
askldajsldkjasdklasd
</div>

</body>
```

---

Without testing it, but each element can only have their each own unique id (if any). What you can use with querySelectorAll is classes (among other things). So each person in a group of humans have their own unique name, but all belong the the class `humans`. Change `id="cImg"` to `class="cImg"` and do use `querySelectorAll(".cImg")` instead.

Comment: OK, what you need it element.style.offsetHeight. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: The problem is using `id`, instead of `class`. @RickardElimää well explain.

Comment: now I get this Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)

Comment: plus it doesn't exist in "style" element

Comment: I added an example of how it should look like. I'm a little bit confused of why your `cImg['0']` works, because it should be `cImg[0]`.

Comment: Me too, I'm confuse about ```cImg['0']``` but it doesn't work like this ```cImg[0]```

Comment: LOL you example works only if I'm writing ```cImg['0']```

Comment: So I can't use, in any case, offsetHeight in a forEach ?

Comment: ... So with JavaScript you can only apply some CSS code to the HTML .... And in the strange things it also works with id .... Maybe I  should go drink wine ;)